# How to find the cause of DNS lookup fail?

Tags: domain-name-system

I run a server with several zones set for each domain, and everything seems to be working for the name to IP translation.

However, when querying a DNS server used by some ISPs, the lookup fails.

How can I find the cause of the problem?

```
$ dig www.jahankitshop.com @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u11-AtomixOS <<>> www.jahankitshop.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12621
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.jahankitshop.com.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.jahankitshop.com.   14399   IN      CNAME   jahankitshop.com.
jahankitshop.com.       599     IN      A       84.241.0.113

;; Query time: 195 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 18 22:34:23 IRDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 79


$ dig www.jahankitshop.com @217.218.155.155

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u11-AtomixOS <<>> www.jahankitshop.com @217.218.155.155
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 16899
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.jahankitshop.com.          IN      A

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 217.218.155.155#53(217.218.155.155)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 18 22:35:19 IRDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

As you can see, the Google's DNS server (`8.8.8.8`) and a lot of other DNS servers are returning an IP address for the requested domain, however, this particular DNS server (`217.218.155.155`) is not returning any answers.

How can I find the cause of this problem, and fix it?

Comment: check your named logs, usually a bad zone file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not in charge of the server `217.218.155.155`, there's nothing **you** can do, except contact whoever is.

To rule out any problems with your zone, I ran it through the [ZoneMaster test engine](https://zonemaster.net/test/4c73f876a025b553), and one thing stood out - you've got two nameservers listed, `ns1.jahankit.ir` and `ns2.jahankit.ir` - but they both resolve to the same IP address. That means that you have no redundancy at all for your nameservers, which is generally considered a very bad thing. But it shouldn't be enough in itself to explain why a particular resolver doesn't handle your domain, except possibly if it tried to get the zone file from ns1.jahankit.ir while it was down, and has cached a negative result. If so, it should probably fix itself after its cache is cleared - again, nothing you can do except contact the server owner.

Answer (score 1):

To put it mildly, your nameserver configuration is all kinds of jacked. The reason why you see different behavior between DNS services is because they are running different software. Google and Comcast prefer the parent side of the delegation, while other nameserver software used by other companies (typically ISC BIND) will initially prefer the parent data, but eventually replace those NS records with the ones found on the child.

### Problem #1: NS record mismatch

The parent NS records do not agree with the child.

```
$ dig +trace +additional jahankitshop.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian <<>> +trace +additional jahankitshop.com NS
;; global options: +cmd

<root and TLD nameservers snipped>

jahankitshop.com.       172800  IN      NS      ns1.jahankit.ir.
jahankitshop.com.       172800  IN      NS      ns2.jahankit.ir.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170724044840 20170717033840 5528 com. jdcKCs8K8hN+9woKgWstJqkhBKOGhmsuSPhovU/SY3CkMWlwI6zclnPG FURMIelNnzIF3SawFa1iKMxCbvAy2/PMc1kpw2zNTR1RVTxOUX+xW1M6 4zP5nbacVe6Gt2eHltBViyMgu7s1DnKVyo/dLQDLtbv23QcXXgnAvKOt q9g=
D6P3MFC6O78JKHA3RVV8L6QOEKF29KOM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - D6P4MCUG3Q6OF15APR8G4RANFGV9PI69 NS DS RRSIG
D6P3MFC6O78JKHA3RVV8L6QOEKF29KOM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170722042100 20170715031100 27302 com. Agmr819TQlkj5Fpdxh6RfNfkNySI5ox6UvzfQYQ2Pi/SJjwmd5QJdh8B tRXjIOmIbk/V0nFL9FdQSeRDEOshv8lJHZBlTxY+RVS5vYL1NMw53gWN Ch3019p0AAyVai9XQF+hyH+/OlGG8VhHrA97uR4F8HW4g4Fb7UIF2IOs 3iU=
;; Received 577 bytes from 192.55.83.30#53(m.gtld-servers.net) in 17 ms

jahankitshop.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns1.dnsfa.xyz.
jahankitshop.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns2.dnsfa.xyz.
;; Received 90 bytes from 88.99.139.8#53(ns2.jahankit.ir) in 108 ms
```

### Problem #2: Missing A records for the NS records defined on the child nameservers.

```
$ dig ns1.dnsfa.xyz A ns2.dnsfa.xyz A  | grep status
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 44257
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 9736
```

Comment: Interesting, that's an entirely different result than what I got when I ran it...